# Return Single Array

Tags: php

I have an array in my mysql database and I would like to show the values of the array on screen.   The array is inside **orden** and I am trying to use function mysql_one_array($query).  I don´t know If I am using the correct function or I should use another. Right now I am not able to see the values of the array. Thanks for your help.

```
<?php

$sql = 'select orden from pedido where id_pedido = "' . $ID . '"';


function mysql_one_array($sql) {
    $query  = mysql_query($sql);
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    return ($result);
}

?>
```

Comment: What does the function return? Do `$result = mysql_one_array($sql); var_dump($result);`

Comment: Have you checked that `mysql_query` succeeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the function with `mysql_one_array( $sql )`. As your code is, the function is only defined.

```
<?php

$sql = 'select orden from pedido where id_pedido = "' . $ID . '"';
$arr = mysql_one_array($sql);
var_dump($arr); # or any other way of printing

function mysql_one_array($sql) {
    $query  = mysql_query($sql);
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    return ($result);
}

?>
```